# Use angular to post form to ASP.NET MVC ActionMethod

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get an ASP.NET MVC form to auto post back to the server using angularjs. When a field reaches a specific amount of characters and is validated, the form will auto send back the ActionResult method I created.

**Question:** Is it possible to send a form post to the Receiving method with angular and auto send the form after it has been validated? Can I use the MVC helpers to validate.

```
@model model.example

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal" ng-app="receiveApp" data-ng-submit="sendForm()" , data-ng-controller="breakDownController">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-2" })
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Uid, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-2" })
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Uid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Uid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LId, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-2" })
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input type="submit" value=@Resources.Receive class="btn btn-default" />
                @Html.ActionLink(Resources.ClearButton, "Receive", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Javascript

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
    App.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.model = {};



        $scope.sendForm = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Receive")',
                data: $scope.model
            }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){

            }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            });
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Cool, what is your question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help

```js
angular.module('formExample', [])
  .controller('FormController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.userType = 'samo';
      $scope.email = "samo@gmail.com"
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
          submitted()
        }


      });

      function submitted() {
        console.log("Form submited");
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="formExample">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
    userType:
    <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
    <input type="email" ng-model="email" required>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span>
    <br>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```